# Variable is defined but never used (no-unused-vars)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

Sorry for the poor English :)
I have used the event Emit and on method to transfer the variable details from one module to another there is this above issue. My code below

In App.vue file

```
<v-btn class="ma-2" @click="closeModal()" tile large color="teal" icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-menu</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

methods: {
    closeModal() {
      this.mini = !this.mini;
      Event.$emit("i-got-clicked", this.mini);
    }
  }
```

In left anvigation file

```
<v-content :v-show="mini">

mounted() {
    Event.$on("i-got-clicked", mini => {
    //This mini is showing as defined but never used
      this.mini = !this.mini;
    });
  }
```

Apprecite any Answers thanks in advance

Comment: You have an extra and unneeded colon in front of your `<v-show>` (:v-show="") which is why your variable appears as unused.

Comment: I checked with both removed it stills it's showing the issue error: 'mini' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src\components\shared\leftNavigation.vue:206:32:
 mounted() { Event.$on("i-got-clicked", mini => { ^ this.mini = !this.mini; }); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the first line here:

```js
Event.$on("i-got-clicked", mini => {
```

This introduces a variable called `mini` and it is not used in the code that follows. `mini` is not the same thing as `this.mini`.

Assuming you don't need it you can write this instead:

```js
Event.$on("i-got-clicked", () => {
```

However, you may want to change the line that follows instead:

```js
Event.$on("i-got-clicked", mini => {
  this.mini = mini;
```

Comment: Thanks, i am using vuex now it is good in transfer data. anyways thanks

Comment: I got this issue again in my old project @skirtle Thanks your () really worked magically. Can u please help me in this issue as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486814/animation-from-one-div-to-another-div-on-click-vuejs

Answer (score 1):

`:v-show` is equivalent to `v-bind:v-show` and that is not what you wanted to do. It would bind a variable with the name `v-show` to that element. Use `v-show` without the unnecessary colon in front of it. Otherwise it is not understood by Vue.

Read more about the `:`-shorthand for `v-bind` [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand).

Comment: It was showing unused variable to thought to bind it but still it shows the issue
error: 'mini' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src\components\shared\leftNavigation.vue:206:32:
 `
mounted() {
     Event.$on("i-got-clicked", mini => {
                               ^
      this.mini = !this.mini;
    });
  }
`

Comment: Do you use the `mini` variable in the template of your `App.vue`? You need to use it if you define it in a component

Comment: Ya define but still not working there is no problem in code the problem is with some no-unused-vars issue in vue

Comment: Do you have some actual variables/imports declared in your component which you don't use? Like `function () { const test = 123; console.log('hello'); }`

Comment: Or do you have a function parameter defined and don't use it in your function body? Like `(test) => { console.log('hello'); }` → this should be `() => { console.log('hello'); }`